# Will quack overflow be accessible after the 1st?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, quack-overflow

I wondered if quack-overflow will be available outside of the 1st April jokes period (even if it's a hacky mean like activate it through the console etc…).
Since rubber-duck-debugging is a technique I use a lot and promote among my colleagues I'd really appreciate this fun support.

Comment: You just keep a physical rubber duck at your desk, and promote your colleagues to talk with it.

Comment: I do, but having SO as a support makes it more serious and gives more credit to the method than I do.

Comment: Usually the comment I see is "Have you asked the duck" ... lame

Comment: The duck might be a trick to fool us. Dont fall into the trick! Its April Fool today! Beware :) I mean the duck ask us to speak louder and we speak louder and louder and it shows just a fun message "Quack"..

Comment: Yes, on a web archive of a Stack Exchange site from April 1st, like [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180401003029/https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DonaldDuck - looks like web archive still links https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Shared/quack.mp3 so the full duck experience won't be available

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All previous Stack Exchange April fools changes have disappeared the moment it is April 2<sup>nd</sup> everywhere in the world. This one is sure to suffer the same fate.

Sometimes the source code is disclosed after the event. If that happens you could host the duck on your own site.

Comment: This time it’s set to run until April 3 UTC because April Fools itself falls on a Sunday this year. This might change once Monday actually rolls around, but at the moment that’s the plan.

Comment: Source code is already available, it's mostly client side. And the server side part (if there's any) won't be sourced out as far as I can tell, @Adam can confirm.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, the server-side part is just access controls/date checks. The markup is rendered into the page and the rest is javascript.

Comment: @AdamLear How do I know whether or not what you said about the date, is not an April Fool's joke?

Comment: @Adam thanks. What about giving non minified version of the JS though?

Comment: @SonicWizard There’s only one way to find out.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I’ll see what we can do. There’s really not much to it, though.

Comment: @Adam yeah, guess most work was done on designing the duck and those cool animations. :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard: https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/quack.en.js

Comment: @IlmariKaronen this is minified version and is almost useless. One need to spend lots of time and efforts to decode it back to readable code. Possible, but hard to do. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No it's not. It does start with a minified copy of the sine-waves script, but you can find the unminified version of that [on GitHub](https://github.com/isuttell/sine-waves). The rest of the code on cdn-dev is not minified. Not that there's much of it.

Comment: @Adam also, who is the developer behind the Duck? Is this you? :)

Comment: @AdamLear  You didn't mention the "year" (in your 1st comment). fingers crossed you mean 2018 ... PS: this answer is clearly not correct ... i.e. the "*This one is sure to suffer the same fate.*" part of it (anywhere in the world it is at least April 2 already ...).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, with design stuff done by Aaron Shekey.

Answer (score 25):

## [Yes, via a mirror](https://unikong.github.io/quackoverflow/)

Comment: **This** should be the accepted answer!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add a "Quack Overflow" memorial:

`crontab -e`

1 * * * * /usr/bin/mpg123 /home/username/Downloads/quack.mp3 &>> /dev/null

**RIP** 4/1/18 - 4/1/18

[image]

[Quack!](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/quack.mp3)

Answer (score -1):

It depends upon what SE designer engineers want to do. If they want to keep it there, they can do. If they want to delete it after first april, they can do that too.

From my side I would say I liked the concept of "Rubber-ducking" (Think-out loudly wikipedia link); although usually personally I think out not "loudly" but more of a visually  (you may term it "brightly" or "colourfully" or "darkly" or whatever you wish), so you may add a scribble pad or modelling clay or a virtual 3-dimensional object too.